# How can I fix contact form 7 not sending message after disabling Rest Api?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I have disabled rest API in Wordpress for non-logged-in users by these codes. How can I fix contact form 7 not sending messages now by modifying the code?

```
//Disable rest api for non-logged in users
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', 'Not logged in.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }
    return $result;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your second if statement to allow Contact form 7 to pass through, by checking if the global $_POST has `_wpcf7` passed.

```
//Disable rest api for non-logged in users
add_filter( 'rest_authentication_errors', function( $result ) {
    if ( ! empty( $result ) ) {
        return $result;
    }
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && empty($_POST['_wpcf7']) ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'rest_not_logged_in', 'Not logged in.', array( 'status' => 401 ) );
    }
    return $result;
});
```

Comment: It works, but after using this, ''the message is successfully sent'' confirmation does not appears anymore.

Comment: Your question was how to fix the email getting sent.  Your additional question is just that.  A different question.

Comment: The form is working and only I know this. The person who is sending the message does not know this as there is no confirmation popup.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you.  But that wasn't your question.